# How to set High maps width and height in percentage for responsiveness?

Tags: dictionary, charts, highcharts, width

I am using highmaps for a world map project and need to set the width and height of the entire canvas in percentage to make it responsive to window resize. (Please specify if there is a better way in high charts to set map responsiveness).

in my index.htm i can easily set width and height just be entering values, but if I enter units such as %, px etc. The map disappears. So it works if I work as follows:

```
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {

  chart: {
     borderWidth: 0,
     width: 100,
     height: 100,
     shadow: false,
     backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
```

You can view a very similar example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/chart/border/

Comment: I was wondering. Is it possible to call methods from within chart: {//method call here}

Comment: You could do [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/JJAn3/).

Comment: Remove this parameters from chart{} object and set it on container (in css).

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" [chart]="highcharts"></div>
```